# Sinon: Test the order of function call and var change

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai, sinon-chai

When we have

```
// arrange
var testVar = 0;
var testFunction = sandbox.stub();

// act
TestClass.TestMethod(); // it changes testVar and calls testFunction
```

Is there a way to test if testVar is changed before testFunction is called?

**Edit:** looks like there isn't. But! You can do something similar if the variable is an object property. Check my own answer below.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Comment: Good one but it's Gecko-only, and I'm doing unit tests here :) I could have my way by using a proxy though...

Comment: Neither Sinon nor proxies can be used to detect if scalar variables change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so looks like it can't really be done.

However, I did find a way to test with object properties. Example pseudo code:

```
before(function() {
    var functionCallOrder = [];

    document.body.classList.add = function() {
        functionCallOrder.push('added class');
    };

    Object.defineProperty(document.body, 'scrollTop', {
        set: function() {
            functionCallOrder.push('changed viewport location');
        }
    });

    it('should set a class before changing the viewport location'), function() {
            // act
            MyModule.methodThatDoesWhatTheDescriptionSays();

            // assert
            expect(functionCallOrder).to.deep.equal([
                'added class',
                'changed viewport location'
            ]);
    });
});
```